# AWS Athena Query date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have date in the following format in a file:

> January 2, 2020 8:15:32 AM UTC

How to query it using Athena? I am trying to query all the rows where date is greater than a specific date.

I don't see above mentioned date format in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-types.html).

Comment: What is the complete format of a line in that file? I'm asking because the comma is likely to cause problems if the file is a CSV. Can you possibly Edit your question and include a few lines as examples?

Answer (score 1):

As @John Rotenstein said you will have problens if your file row has columns split by `,` because your date columns also uses `,`.

Nevertheless here is how you can cast your string `January 2, 2020 8:15:32 AM UTC` to date in Athena.
Athena uses presto in the backend and you can use the [parse_datetime](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?highlight=parse_datetime#parse_datetime) with the corresponding format to convert your string to a date.

> parse_datetime(string, format) → timestamp with time zone

```
WITH t(x) AS (VALUES 'January 2, 2020 8:15:32 AM UTC')
SELECT parse_datetime(x, 'MMM d, YYYY hh:mm:ss a z') 
FROM t;
```

produces the output

```
"_col0"
"2020-01-02 08:15:32.000 UTC"
```