# Hardcode date in SELECT clause (Athena)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Would anyone have any advice on how to hardcode a specific date into my SELECT clause?

I'm trying to force a date into my query so I can reference it later, but unsure how to go about this.

Thanks in advance!
Sam

TL;DR Having issues writing a specific date into the SELECT in Athena/SQL

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345635/how-to-select-several-hardcoded-sql-rows) solves your doubts

Comment: Can you please share some query?

Comment: You mean like `SELECT DATE '2023-07-05' AS birthday`?

Comment: Use whatever format you want and parse it ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69716449/125981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help all - I've managed to do what I needed to do by using this:

```
(CAST("date_trunc"('month', "date_add"('month', -1, current_date)) AS date)
```

This has locked the date I need to use until the next month rolls around and it'll then update accordingly.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways to hardcode a timestamp to a column:

```
select 
     timestamp '2023-07-07 12:34:56' as ts,
     date '2023-07-07' as dt,
     from_unixtime(1688733296) as unix_time
```

If you're using Athena engine v3.0 (Trino), you can use this reference:
https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Otherwise, you'll want the Presto documentation:
[https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#)